# Yii2 - Kartik/EditableColumn in GridView does not save the value

Tags: arrays, json, yii2, kartik-v

I have a problem using the EditableColumn in Yii2, it does not save me the values of the change,
in my GridView index I have the following:

```
[
   'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
   'attribute'=>'nombreDestino',
   'editableOptions' => [
   'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
   'data'=> $claveCliente,
   'formOptions' => [
                  'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['pru', 
                  ['id'=>$idOrigen,'idD'=>$idDestino]])
                    ]
 ],
```

in my Controller I have the following:

```
public function actionPru()
    {
        $val = implode(",",$_GET[1]['id']);
        $val2 = implode(",",$_GET[1]['idD']);

        if(Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable'))
        {
            $nombreDestino = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
            $Destino = RelClientes::findOne($nombreDestino);

            $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'','message'=>'']);
            $post = [];
            $posted = current($_POST['RelClientes']);

            if($Destino->load($posted))
            {
                $Destino -> save(false);
            }
            echo $out;
            return;
        }
    }
```

the JSON returns empty to me, when making the change and clicking the save button, in the GridView if I make the change but when reloading the page the change is not saved.

RelClientes is my model.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `Kartik\grid\Gridview`, and not `yii\grid\GridView`. You should look into the [**`DOCS`**](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#editable-column-action) for EditableColumnAction to configure the action for the updating and you do not need to pass any `id`.

> ### Processing Editable Data
>
> In addition to the editable input value that will be returned via form POST action, the Editable Column
>   automatically stores the following hidden inputs, for retrieval via
>   your controller action:
>   - `editableIndex` the grid row index to which the editable data belongs.
>
> - `editableKey` the grid primary key to which the editable data belongs. If the grid's data has a primary key which is numeric or
>     string, then it would be returned as is. However, if the grid data has
>     a composite primary key (array) or an object as a key (as used in
>     mongo db), then this will return a PHP serialized string, that can be
>     parsed using the [**`PHP unserialize method`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

So replace your action with the following function in your controller

```
public function actions() {

        return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge ( parent::actions () , [
                    'pru' => [
                        'class' => kartik\grid\EditableColumnAction::class ,
                        'modelClass' => RelClientes::class ,
                        'outputValue' => function ($model , $attribute , $key , $index) {
                            return $model->$attribute;
                        } ,
                        'outputMessage' => function($model , $attribute , $key , $index) {
                            return '';
                        } ,
                    ]

                    ]);
    }
```

and update your `EditableColumn` definition to the following

```
[
    'class' => kartik\grid\EditableColumn::class ,
    'attribute' => 'name' ,
    'editableOptions' => [
        'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST ,
        'data'=> $claveCliente,
        'formOptions' => [
           'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to([ 'pru' ])
        ]
    ] ,
] ,
```

Hope it helps you out.